# Citation without author's first name

Tags: natbib

I did not find the solution to my exact problem so I open a new post. 
I would like to cite in the text like this: (Doe, 2001) but with my code I have (Doe, J., 2001). Can you please suggest me how can I change the code to avoid the first name?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
...
\begin{document}
\autocite{Doe2001}
...
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

The .bib file is imported from Mendeley and it's like this

```
@article{Doe2001, 
title = {{...}}, 
year = {2001}, 
journal = {...}, 
author = {Doe, J.}, 
number = {...}, 
pages = {...}, 
volume = {...}, 
doi = {...}, 
issn = {...}, 
keywords = {...}
```

Comment: Welcomew to tex.sx.  The reference from Mendeley *does* have a first initial.  What it doesn't do is separate the initial from the surname.  Add a comma: `author = {Doe, J.},`

Comment: @barbarabeeton unfortunately I wrote wrong, the comma was already there. I changed the code... any other idea?

Comment: Oh, dear!  The only other thing I can think of to try is to reverse the two parts of the name: `author = {J. Doe},`